# 3 nested loops: Optimizing a simple simulation for speed

Tags: python, montecarlo, markov-chains

#### Background

I've come across a puzzle. Here it is:

> One day, an alien comes to Earth. Every day, each alien does one of four things, each with equal probability to:
>
> - Kill himself
> - Do nothing
> - Split himself into two aliens (while killing himself)
> - split himself into three aliens (while killing himself)
>
> What is the probability that the alien species eventually dies out entirely?

[Link to the source and the solution, problem #10](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/07/20-challenging-job-interview-puzzles-which-every-analyst-solve-atleast/)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve the problem theoretically. Then I moved on to simulate it with a basic Markov Chain and Monte Carlo simulation in mind.

*This was not asked to me in an interview. I learned the problem from a friend, then found the link above while searching for mathematical solutions.*

#### Reinterpreting the question

We start with the number of aliens `n = 1`. `n` has a chance to not change, be decremented by `1`, be incremented by `1`, and be decremented by `2`, %25 for each. If `n` is incremented, i.e. aliens multiplied, we repeat this procedure for `n` times again. This corresponds to each alien will do its thing again. I have to put an upper limit though, so that we stop simulating and avoid a crash. `n` is likely to increase and we're looping `n` times again and again.

If aliens somehow go extinct, we stop simulating again since there's nothing left to simulate.

After `n` reaches zero or the upper limit, we also record the population (it will be either zero or some number `>= max_pop`).

I repeat this many times and record every result. At the end, number of zeros divided by total number of results should give me an approximation.

#### The code

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

pop_max = 100
iter_max = 100000

results = np.zeros(iter_max, dtype=int)

for i in range(iter_max):
    n = 1
    while n > 0 and n < pop_max:
        for j in range(n):
            x = randint(1, 4)
            if x == 1:
                n = n - 1
            elif x == 2:
                continue
            elif x == 3:
                n = n + 1
            elif x == 4:
                n = n + 2
    results[i] = n

print( np.bincount(results)[0] / iter_max )
```

`iter_max` and `pop_max` can be changed indeed, but I thought if there are 100 aliens, the probability that they go extinct would be negligibly low. This is just a guess though, I haven't done anything to calculate a (more) proper upper limit for population.

This code gives promising results, fairly close to the real answer which is approximately %41.4.

#### Some outputs

```
> python aliens.py
0.41393
> python aliens.py
0.41808
> python aliens.py
0.41574
> python aliens.py
0.4149
> python aliens.py
0.41505
> python aliens.py
0.41277
> python aliens.py
0.41428
> python aliens.py
0.41407
> python aliens.py
0.41676
```

#### Aftermath

I'm okay with the results but I can't say the same for the time this code takes. It takes around 16-17 seconds :)

How can I improve the speed? How can I optimize loops (especially the `while` loop)? Maybe there's a much better approach or better models?

Comment: You may want to post this at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I think the speed junkies gather over there. `;-)`

Comment: @BramVanroy Good call, will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize your inner loop by generating `n` random integers all at once with numpy (much faster), and get rid of all your if statements using arithmatic instead of boolean logic.

```
while...: 
    #population changes by (-1, 0, +1, +2) for each alien
    n += np.random.randint(-1,3, size=n).sum()
```

Using your exact code for everything else (you could probably find other optimizations elsewhere) I went from 21.2 sec to 4.3 sec using this one change.

Without changing the algorithm (ie solving with a method other than monte carlo) I don't see any other sweeping changes that could make it much faster until you get into compiling to machine code (which is fortunately very easy if you have numba installed).

I won't give an entire tutorial on just-in-time compilation that numba performs, but instead, I'll just share my code and make note of the changes I made:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
from numba import njit, int32, prange

@njit('i4(i4)')
def simulate(pop_max): #move simulation of one population to a function for parallelization
    n = 1
    while 0 < n < pop_max:
        n += np.sum(randint(-1,3,n))
    return n

@njit('i4[:](i4,i4)', parallel=True)
def solve(pop_max, iter_max):
    #this could be easily simplified to just return the raio of populations that die off vs survive to pop_max
    # which would save you some ram (though the speed is about the same)
    results = np.zeros(iter_max, dtype=int32) #numba needs int32 here rather than python int
    for i in prange(iter_max): #prange specifies that this loop can be parallelized
        results[i] = simulate(pop_max)
    return results

pop_max = 100
iter_max = 100000

t = time()
print( np.bincount(solve(pop_max, iter_max))[0] / iter_max )
print('time elapsed: ', time()-t)
```

Compilation with parallelization gets the speed of evaluation down to about 0.15 seconds on my system.

Comment: Yours took 4,3s including numba? The pure python, no numpy solution I did does 100k samples in 4.84s on http://www.pyfiddle.io - no idea what specs the pyfiddle env has though

Comment: @PatrickArtner OP's soln: 21.2 sec, my soln: 4.3 sec, my soln with numba: 0.6 sec (including compilation). (i5-6300U @ 2.4 GHz)

Comment: You can use `chache=True` to avoid the recompilation step every time the interpreter is restarted...

Comment: @max9111 caching isn't compatible with loop parallelization, which in this case can give us even more speed

Comment: I didn't know we could use `randint` like that. That alone gives a huge speed-up. I also didn't know about numba, thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

No numpy solution, takes about 5s for 100k simulations:

```
from random import choices

def simulate_em():
    def spwn(aliens):
        return choices(range(-1,3), k=aliens)

    aliens = {1:1}
    i = 1
    while aliens[i] > 0 and aliens[i] < 100:    
        i += 1
        num = aliens[i-1]
        aliens[i] = num + sum(spwn(num))

    # commented for speed
    # print(f"Round {i:<5} had {aliens[i]:>20} alien alive.")
    return (i,aliens[i])
```

Testing it (about 5s on pyfiddle.io):

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.now()    
d = {}
wins = 0
test = 100000
for k in range(test):
    d[k] = simulate_em()
    wins += d[k][1]>=100

print(1-wins/test)         # 0.41532
print(datetime.now()-t)    # 0:00:04.840127
```

So its takes about 5 seconds for 100k testruns...

Output's (of 2 runs):

```
Round 1     had                    1 alien alive.
Round 2     had                    3 alien alive.
Round 3     had                    6 alien alive.
Round 4     had                    9 alien alive.
Round 5     had                    7 alien alive.
Round 6     had                   13 alien alive.
Round 7     had                   23 alien alive.
Round 8     had                   20 alien alive.
Round 9     had                   37 alien alive.
Round 10    had                   54 alien alive.
Round 11    had                   77 alien alive.
Round 12    had                  118 alien alive.

Round 1     had                    1 alien alive.
Round 2     had                    0 alien alive.
```

By using `amount_of_aliens` + `sum` over `choices(range(-1,3),k=amount_of_aliens)` you get the summations easier and fill your dict faster? If your amount of aliens ever drops below 0 they are extinct.